# How to isolate blocks of text containing specific words and remove the others?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a project trying to extract data out of email logs. Basically I want to clean a large .txt file of irrelevant emails, and then count specific data within each of the relevant emails.

Relevant emails can be identified by a **JACKPOT WORD** within the body of the email. But I'm really trying to get **important info** that is unique to each email.

Both **JACKPOT WORD** and **important info** will be located on different lines / places on each email.

I'm having issue weeding out non-relevant emails from the file.

I've managed to separate each email with headers and footers but I'm at a loss on how to remove the irrelevant emails.

This is what the file looks like now:

```
--- new email ---
irrelevant email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablabla**looks like important info**blablablablabla
--- end email ---

--- new email ---
**relevant** email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablab**JACKPOT WORD**lablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablabla**important info**blablabla
--- end email ---

--- new email ---
irrelevant email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablablablabl**looks like important info**ablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
--- end email ---

--- new email ---
**relevant** email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablab**JACKPOT WORD**lablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablabla**important info**blablabla
--- end email ---
```

The result I want is :

```
--- new email ---
**relevant** email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablab**JACKPOT WORD**lablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablabla**important info**blablabla
--- end email ---

--- new email ---
**relevant** email that spans over multiple lines
blablablablablablablab**JACKPOT WORD**lablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablabla**important info**blablabla
--- end email ---
```

I first tried using .find(**JACKPOT WORD**) but I would only get the individual line and these do not usually contain the **important info**, I'm looking for (usually on another line within the email).

I've tried splitting each email to a file (successfully) using:

```
splittxt = '--- new email ---'
endtxt = '--- end email ---'

fread = open("outputfile.txt")
count = 1
fwrite = open("email%s.txt" % (count), 'w')
for line in fread:
    if line.startswith(splittxt):
        fwrite.close()
        count += 1
        fwrite = open("email%s.txt" % (count), 'w')
        fwrite.write(line + "\n")
    else:
        fwrite.write(line + "\n")
fwrite.close()
fread.close()
```

This create a long list of .txt files named email1.txt, email2.txt, email3.txt, etc.. with each individual email.

I have no idea how to read those files and write to a new file only the emails that contain **JACKPOT WORD**.

I tried the following, it runs but returns a empty result.txt file.

```
count = 1
keeptxt = '**JACKPOT WORD**'

for i in range(1000):       
    fread = open("email%s.txt" % (count)).readlines()
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in fread:
            if keeptxt in line:
                with open(fread) as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I'm running out of ideas. I'm not certain creating all these individual files is the best way to go about it either (there's thousands of emails...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to write any other files until you've gathered all the information you're interested in. Just put everything into a temporary list, and then write out the results from that:

```
# gather all the relevant data first...
NEW_EMAIL = '--- new email ---'
END_EMAIL = '--- end email ---'
JACKPOT = '**JACKPOT WORD**'

email = []
jackpots = []
starting = True
with open('input.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        if starting:
            if line.startswith(NEW_EMAIL):
                # start gathering new email lines
                email = []
                starting = False
        elif line.startswith(END_EMAIL):
            # start looking for a new email
            starting = True
        else:
            email.append(line)
            if JACKPOT in line:
                # only keep jackpot emails
                jackpots.append(email)

# now write out the final file...
with open('output.txt', 'w') as stream:
    for email in jackpots:
        stream.write('%s\n%s%s\n\n' % (
            NEW_EMAIL, ''.join(email), END_EMAIL))
```

Comment: You're right, this is a lot better. I'm very new at programming and I was having issues visualizing what was happening, so the files helped a little :). After reading your code thoroughly I understand the logic and will definitely be re-using it. Many thanks ekhumoro, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, certainly creating one file per email is going to use a lot of space for no reason, but hey, you've got to start somewhere with your fiddling.

Cobbling together something from the code you have, this should create a single file containing only the emails which contain the jackpot word.

```
splittxt = '--- new email ---\n'
keeptxt = '**JACKPOT WORD**'

fread = open("outputfile.txt")
fwrite = open("jackpotEmails.txt", 'w')

thisEmail = ""
hasJackpot = False
for line in fread:
    if line.startswith(splittxt):
        # if the previous email had the jackpot word, then write out that email
        if hasJackpot :
            fwrite.write(thisEmail)

        # new email
        thisEmail = splittxt

    if not hasJackpot:
        hasJackpot = keeptxt in line

    thisEmail += line

fwrite.close()
fread.close()
```

Is extracting all the relevant emails into a file all you wanted to do, or do you also want to automatically extract the **important info** bits? That seems harder, and we'll need more information about what's in the **important info** bits.

(your last example doesn't work because when you read files from disk, they have a cursor like in MS Word that moves through the file as you read it; when you do file.readlines() the whole file is read at once and the cursor is moved all the way to the end, then when you do file.read() later, there's nothing to read since the cursor is already at the end. Usually when people use file.readlines() they then close the file and only act on that mega string.)

Last comment: if you're going to do more text analysis in the future, I suggest spending some time looking into the Natural Language Tookkit http://www.nltk.org/ which is a big giant text processing tool for python. Spending some time reading tutorials will give you an idea 1) what tools exist 2) the standard ways that people approach text analysis problems.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation as to why my example didn't work, as I'm very new to programming. I will definitely look into the Natural Language Tookkit. The important info bits are urls that I managed to capture with re.search. Thanks Mike!